# How to setup JBPM as a springboot microservice?

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, jbpm

I am trying to start JBPM 7 as a Spring-Boot micro service can someone guide on the necessary steps and configurations required to start the service?

- I tried the below link
- http://mswiderski.blogspot.com/2018/01/spring-boot-starters-for-jbpm-and-kie.html

The kie-server is no longer available at https://start.spring.io/.

Kindly let me know, the possible solutions.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take a tour around: [how to ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) before continuing your trip.

Answer (score 1):

Try to configure and generate application from [JBPM Spring Boot link](https://start.jbpm.org/)